# how to detect Adobe Acrobat Reader installation in computer (not just browser) during Setup?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-project, adobe-reader

im creating a VS setup installer for my C# project. I need the client's machine to first install Adobe Acrobat Reader X before proceeding to the actual installation.

How do i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a custom prerequisite for Acrobat Reader X. For this you can use the [bootstrapper manifest generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg).

To detect it you can search for this registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\10.0\InstallPath
```

After generating the package manifests, you can add all these files (including the package) in a separate folder in the Visual Studio prerequisites folder, for example:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages
```

You can then select the prerequisite by clicking Properties on your setup project in Solution Explorer.

Comment: the bootstrapper gives me exceptions, i cant proceed. any other 3rd party bootstrappers you recommend?

Comment: What exceptions? There are no other bootstrapper manifest generators for Visual Studio. An alternative would be a commercial setup authoring tool.

Comment: here's a partial: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Attempted to access a path that is not on the disk.
   at Microsoft.Bootstrapper.Paths.get_DefaultRootBootstrapper()

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a folder which doesn't exist or cannot be accessed. How are you using this tool? Did you use "File" -> "New" -> "Package Manifest"?